# Can not align absolute div in center

Tags: css

Probably it's relate to the fact that its position is `absolute`, but still how would you center an `absolute` positioned `div` ?

Using `top`, instead of `margin-top` ***works***, but `left` instead of `margin-left` **won't affect it**. Why ?

```
.title
{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 10%;
  top : 80%;
}




<div class="title fontHugeTitle2"><h1> The Best  In Town </h1></div>
```

Comment: What is your html code? Can you add full related code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left: auto; right: auto` won't work like `margin: 0 auto` for centering the div, but you have a fixed width and you can just set the `left` property to half of what's left e.g. `left: 5%`

Comment: Thanks, I don't get you :) I understand what to do, but don't understand why its not working with left/right auto

Comment: Your solution works but why mine will not ? whats the logic behind ?

Comment: @Curnelious ´left:auto´ and ´right:auto´ is not for centering layer. They are for override existing positions. For example, if you want to animate layer size from left to it's actual size, first set ´left:0´ then set ´left:auto´ after an event.

Comment: @Curnelious as to the expected result, the docs say - 'When both left and right are defined, the position of the element is overspecified. When this is the case, the left value has precedence when the container is left-to-right (thus, the computed value of right is set to -left); the right value has precedence when the container is right-to-left (thus, the computed value of left is set to -right).' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky i didn't set left and right so the docs you just showed is not relevant. I did set them to be auto which by the docs should center the element. Still not sure why absolute element will not listen to them.

Comment: @Curnelious can you link the part of the docs you are referring to, I'm pretty sure that's only applicable to the margin property

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Change

```
<div class="title fontHugeTitle2"><h1> The Best  In Town </h1></div>
```

To

```
<div class="fontHugeTitle2"><h1 class="title"> The Best  In Town </h1></div>
```